# Partitioning lists to execute parallel tasks

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I fire tasks to download multiple URLs.

```
    Dim downloadTasksQuery As IEnumerable(Of Task(Of Boolean)) =
        From company In companies Select DownloadCompanyFromYahooAsync(company, numberOfDays)
    ' ***Use ToList to execute the query and start the download tasks. 
    Dim downloadTasks As IEnumerable(Of Task(Of Boolean)) = downloadTasksQuery.ToList()

    Await Task.WhenAll(downloadTasks)
```

The `companies` list is kind of containing 2000 URLs. I am observing that URLs added towards the end of the list are more frequently timing out. I have retry logics in place and am handling this timeout situation, which downloads the URL on the next try. However, I dont want to give preferential treatment to a URL just because it appears in the beginning of the list.

Hence was trying to think if we can fork 4 main tasks chunking the URL list into 500 each (probably more manageable) and then use the above code. However, am not able to figure out a way to introduce that without having to rewrite too much in the above code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Something more like this:

```
    Dim chunkPart As OrderablePartitioner(Of Tuple(Of Integer, Integer)) = Partitioner.Create(1, companies.Count, 500)

    Parallel.ForEach(chunkPart, Sub(chunkRange)
                                    For i As Integer = chunkRange.Item1 To chunkRange.Item2 - 1
                                        Dim downloadTasksQuery As IEnumerable(Of Task(Of Boolean)) =
                                        From company In companies.Skip(chunkRange.Item1).Take((chunkRange.Item2 - chunkRange.Item1) + 1) Select DownloadCompanyFromYahooAsync(company, numberOfDays)
                                        Dim downloadTasks As IEnumerable(Of Task(Of Boolean)) = downloadTasksQuery.ToList()
                                        Await Task.WhenAll(downloadTasks)
                                    Next
                                End Sub
```

This is with minimal code changes, but the issue is that I cannot use `Await` inside a `Parallel.ForEach`.

Any suggestions pls to change this.

Comment: Something more like using Parallel.ForEach with a partition. Posting an updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a VB.NET guy, but I think Stephen Toub's good post on [implementing a simple ForEachAsync](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/implementing-a-simple-foreachasync-part-2/) might be helpful to you.

Some code snippet from his post, it allow you to limit the number of operatons that are able to run in parallel.

```cs
public static Task ForEachAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int dop, Func<T, Task> body) 
{ 
  return Task.WhenAll( 
    from partition in Partitioner.Create(source).GetPartitions(dop) 
    select Task.Run(async delegate { 
      using (partition) 
        while (partition.MoveNext()) 
          await body(partition.Current); 
  })); 
}
```

For your specific question, you can then use this as such:

```cs
public async Task DownloadForAllCompanies(List<string> companies, int numberOfDays)
{
  await companies.ForEachAsync(4, async company =>
  {
    await DownloadCompanyFromYahooAsync(company, numberOfDays);
  });
}
```